# Get data from XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml

below is part of my XML where I try to get data from, basicly I need to insert them to array where "role" is key and "entry" is value.

Here is XML:

```
<CommunicationDetailList>
  <CommunicationDetail>
    <Role>Phone1</Role>
    <Entry>727831333</Entry>
  </CommunicationDetail>
  <CommunicationDetail>
    <Role>Mobile</Role>
    <Entry>727834125</Entry>
  </CommunicationDetail>
  <CommunicationDetail>
    <Role>Fax1</Role>
    <Entry>123456789</Entry>
  </CommunicationDetail>
  <CommunicationDetail>
    <Role>EMail1</Role>
    <Entry>moj@mail.sk</Entry>
 </CommunicationDetail>                             
</CommunicationDetailList>
```

This is my PHP code, unfotunately it doesn't work correctly (add just first one not rest of it, so I have access just to Phone1):

```
        //this is somewhere on top of my code
        $doc = new DOMDocument();

        //Load XML to DOM
        $doc->loadXml($xml);
        .
        .
         // here I parse rest of XML, where `<tags>` are unique
        .
        .
        //and here is that important part
        $communicationDetails = $doc->getElementsByTagName( "CommunicationDetailList" );
        foreach( $communicationDetails as $detail )
        {  
          $keys = $detail->getElementsByTagName( "Role" );
          $key = $keys->item(0)->nodeValue;

          $values = $detail->getElementsByTagName( "Entry" );
          $value = $values->item(0)->nodeValue;

          //adding login and password to array              
          $data[$key] = $value;

        }
```

Can someone help me to access to this XML

Comment: _"unfotunately it doesn't work correctly"_ And why doesn't it work correctly? What errors are you getting? Have you done some debugging to locate where the error is occurring?

Comment: Hi @Epodax I belieave we just miss each other, I was editing question , answer on it is in bracket, so : No error but just first key + value is added to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may be it help

```
foreach( $communicationDetails as $detail )
{  
    $keys = $detail->getElementsByTagName( "Role" );
    $values = $detail->getElementsByTagName( "Entry" );
    $length = $keys->length;
        for($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++)
        {
            $key = $keys->item($i)->nodeValue;
            $value = $values->item($i)->nodeValue;
            $data[$key] = $value;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `SimpleXMLElement` like this

```
<?php

$xml = 'data.xml';
//load xml from file
$doc = simplexml_load_file($xml);

// or load from string
// $doc = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

foreach($doc->CommunicationDetail as $detail){

    //print $detail->Role . ' - ' . $detail->Entry . PHP_EOL;

    $data[(string)$detail->Role] = (string)$detail->Entry;
    // we cast the xml elements as strings to be used as keys and values in the array
}

print_r($data);

//output is 
Array
(
    [Phone1] => 727831333
    [Mobile] => 727834125
    [Fax1] => 123456789
    [EMail1] => moj@mail.sk
)
```

Comment: Hey @Alex Andrei, thanks for advise, I give you thump up for this nice solution. However I need to use DOM for some other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with

```
$item(0)
```

If you were to use a iterated loop like

```
 for ($i=0; $i<count($keys); $i++) { echo $keys[$i]; }
```

Then it would go through the entire array.